# Finding least difference between a date (given only the day and month) and today in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I am writing a bash script which will print the number of weeks,days and hours left for user's birthday from the time it is run. The user will only fill in the his birth-date and month.
I searched and found out that we can take difference of two dates:

```
let DIFF=(`date +%s -d 20150108`-`date +%s -d today`)/86400
echo $DIFF
```

The above script will print the number of days left for the given date. We can similarly find out the number of weeks and hours. 
But the problem is, if user gives only the birth-date excluding the year, (here he gives only 8 Jan) how do I figure out the least difference possible between upcoming birthday and today?

Example, if the birthday just passed , then I have to consider the birthday which comes next year.

Comment: do your homework by yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to count days is to use `date`'s `%j` format code, which returns the day number in the year (an three-digit integer between 001 and 366, inclusive). (Note: we prepend `1` to the output of `date +%j` to make it a four-digit integer not starting with a `0`, to avoid octal conversion.)

```
DATE="Feb 7"

TODAY=1$(date +%j)
BDAY=1$(date +%j -d "$DATE")
if ((BDAY<TODAY)); then
  BDAY=1$(date +%j -d "$DATE "$(($(date +%Y)+1)))
fi
DAYS_TO_GO=$(($BDAY-$TODAY))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just check if the date happened already this year, and if it did append next year to the input.

```
> input="8 Feb" 
> input=$(date -d "$input" '+%d %b')
> [[ $(date -d "$input" '+%s') -lt $(date -d "$(date '+%d/%m/%y')" '+%s') ]] && input="$input $(( $(date '+%Y') + 1 ))"
> let DIFF=(`date +%s -d "$input"`-`date +%s -d today`)/86400
> echo $DIFF
360
```

Couple of caveats. 2nd line strips year and other information (time, etc...) from date if user enters it with that. And `$(date -d "$(date '+%d/%m/%y')" '+%s')` in third line is needed so it compares only against the current date, rather than the date with time.